# notepad++ user defined language folding open and close

Tags: notepad++, basic

There seems to be a problem with N++ folding properly.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/E3XzW.jpg)

I set the Open and Close parameter to IF and END IF respectively, then set a styler.
In the code however, it does not seem to match the IF and END IF properly. It will collapse way more code than is within the IF THEN bracket. Am I doing something wrong?

Edit: Here is a code snipped an a screenshot. If I collapse the first "IF" Statement, the whole program collapses. Thanks. Notepad++ v.6.7.8 W7 no extensions.

```
IF EVOLT$ = "Y" AND PTCONN$ = "WYE" THEN 

    IF
    END IF

              'A BUNCH OF CODE

END IF


IF EVOLT$ = "N" THEN


            'SOME CODE HERE TOO

END IF
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Could you help out people trying to replicate this problem by giving a [Minimal, Complete and Verifible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). For example, can you tell which version of N++ you are using, what OS, any extensions, etc...

Comment: Thanks Jonathan you right i didn't put enough info. I just edited the post thanks

Comment: Looks like it's interpreting the `IF` keyword in `END IF` as an opening command. Have you tried to close with `ENDIF` just to see if it works?

Comment: Petaflop that's actually what makes the most sense. Tried to change all the "end if" to ENDIF and then changed it in user defined language.. Still trying though because it's probably something like that

Comment: @Petaflop Good news and bad news. The way to get it to work is to go into "Folding in code 2 style" then mark the Open as "IF" and the Middle as "THEN" and the Close as "END IF" and include the quotation. The code 2 style is case sensitive i read (http://www.thevalvepage.com/swmonkey/2015/08/19/notepad-user-defined-languages/) Now the problem is a single line IF THEN statement has no END IF and that's not really supported by N++